# How to Download a word file using streamlit

Tags: python, byte, docx, streamlit

I am trying to setup a button that takes takes files from a local directory and lets you download them

this is my code right now :

```
import io
import streamlit as st  
import docx

f = open('Analysis.docx','rb')

doc_download = docx.Document(f)
print(doc_download)
f.close()
bio = io.BytesIO()

doc_download.save(bio)
if doc_download:
    st.download_button(
        label="Click here to download",
        data=bio.getvalue(),
        file_name="Report.docx",
        mime="docx"
        )
```

Comment: Try looking at [How to download a file in Streamlit?](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/using-streamlit/how-download-file-streamlit)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you help us understand the use case a little more? If the file already exists locally on the machine where you're running the app, why would you want to download it from the app?

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet should solve your problem

```
with open('myfile.docx', 'rb') as f:
   st.download_button('Download Docx', f, file_name='New_File.docx')
```